# ModelContext + the "query" returns nothing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm beginner in ASP.NET MVC4.

I've created a model with a table in my data base. I've two entry in my table.

I try to send a entry in my controller but my modelcontext returns null. Here is my code:

My controller:

```
enter code herepublic class HomeController : Controller
{
    //connection à la table
    private AnnonceModelContext db = new AnnonceModelContext();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        AnnonceModel last_annonce = db.Annonces.Find(2);
        if (last_annonce == null)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Pas d'annonce pour le moment";
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            return View(last_annonce);
        }
    }
```

My views:

```
@model wiki_bird.Models.AnnonceModel
<section id="annonce" class="content-wrapper">
        <h1>Annonce</h1>
        <p>
           @ViewBag.Message
            <br />
           @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.titre)
        </p>
    </section>
```

last_annonce is always null then that my table "Annonce" in my database is not empty!

I hope you can help me! Sorry for my bad english i'm not english.

Regards,

sushi

Comment: Check if the database has `Annonce` with `id=2`?

Comment: i've screenshoot my table in my project: http://img842.imageshack.us/img842/4525/id2i.png

Comment: Is the Id-field in the `Annonces` marked as a primary key? Are you using the Code First approach or did you create you Model from the database (i.e. an edmx)?

Comment: i followed this tutoriel for create my model and my table: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_database.asp